# ESP32 Serial buffer in the PlatformIO works different fron the Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino, esp32, platformio

Good afternoon people

I’m having problems using the ES32 Serial buffer.

My code below has the function of storing the data received on the Serial port and print this data in the Serial Monitor, but it works one way on the Arduino IDE and on PlatformIO it works the other way.

Code compiled in the Arduino IDE test:
[image]

Code compiled in the PlatformIO test:
[image]

Can anyone help me with a solution?

Thank you very much in advance

Below is the code example.

```
    #include <Arduino.h>
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
     int i = 0;
     while(Serial.available()>0){
        char a = Serial.read();
        Serial.print(a);
        Serial.print(", ");

        i = 1;
        }
     if(i == 1) 
     {
      Serial.println("");
       i = 0;

  for(int r = 0; r < 61; r++){char u = Serial2.read();}
       
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is "one way" and what is the "other way"? Please elaborate. And for the sake of readers: format it properly. It's extremely hard to to understand this mess and it is just 20 lines of code...

Comment: Hello, i update my question, if you can help me i apreciate it

Comment: Looks like Arduino IDE generated bit slower code and the buffer is getting filled fast enough to not jump out of the `while (Serial.available())` loop. But I can't see any problem in it. You read one character, and the next one hasn't arrived yet..

Comment: I believe this is it, I used the command Serial.flush () and the result of the code by PlatformIO was a little more similar to the result of the Arduino IDE